# The source phone number provided is not yet verified for your account

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

Getting an error that phone number is not verified when I add a callerId.

When placing a call it returns:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Twilio\Exceptions\RestException: [HTTP 400]
> Unable to create record: The source phone number provided, XXXX, is
> not yet verified for your account.

The strange part is that it only gives this error when callerId value is set.

So for example

```
$call = $client->calls
    ->create(
        "+x", // to
        "+x", // from
        [
            "url" => "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml",
        ]
    );
```

Does work

but the following produces that error.

```
$call = $client->calls
    ->create(
        "+x", // to
        "+x", // from
        [
            "url" => "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml",
            "callerId" => 'SomeValue',
        ]
    );
```

The only difference is that **callerId** gets set.

From number was purchased, account is not trial and SID is valid since it works without callerId field

Answer (score 1):

Error is returned because it looks like Twilio is trying to use the value of callerId as the phone number. So it looks like you can't set a caller ID in the form of a word, it has to be a numeric value

> I'm sorry the docs are not clear about this, but CallerId works the
> same a From. It must be Twilio phone number or verified non-Twilio
> phone number in your account. It cannot be a word or name. Twilio
> phone numbers do not support CNAM (caller name) database entries, so
> it is not possible to specify a name that the call recipient sees, if
> their carrier does CNAM lookups.
>
> When you specify From, you do not need to pass CallerId.